# Why intermittent decryption errors on RSA Encrypted Block?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa

### RSA Encryption/Decryption Error

I am having a problem with an RSA encryption algorithm.  I have an app (APP1) on an embedded device.  The device has
a proprietary (old) embedded OS.  I have 1 RSA crypto function ("rsa_calc") that I am using.  In APP1
it has the public key of an RSA Key Pair.  My issue is periodically, some encryptions can't be decrypted
in the receiving application APP2 (modern application/os).  I am using BP-TOOLS Crypto Calculator to verify
results.  I have included the trace of 2 encryptions below.  The first works, i.e. it can be decrypted using
BP-TOOLS Crypto Calculator.  The Second cannot.  The vast majority of encryptions verify, but every now and again
some do not.

The issue appears to be based on the input data to be encrypted.  Taking my traces, I found a working value, and a
non-working value.  And performed the encryptions.  I get the same results.  So basically encrypting some data works,
other not so much.  Please see traces below.

This leads me to believe I am having some padding error.  The RSA encrypt function does not document padding schemes.
I am not implementing any padding manually other than using a 128 byte buffer.  On BP-TOOLS Crypto Calculator,
I am using "No Padding" on the decryption, it only seems to work when I select that.
If I select "PKCS1", I get padding errors when decrypting.  There is no error decrypting the data on BP-TOOLS, I just
don't get clear text/original text.

I am not concerned about the strength of the encryption and not using padding etc.  I am just trying to get this to
work consistently.  Do I have to implement one of the padding schemes for RSA manually?  Does padding make certain
RSA buffers impossible to decrypt (I wouldn't think so, I know it weakens the cipher, don't care)?

Can anyone see some other issue that may be causing my problem?

Thanks for the help

### Function Documentation

```
rsa_calc()
Performs a public key RSA computation. It supports keys up to 2048 bits and exponent values of 2, 3, and 65537.

Prototype:
  int rsa_calc(unsigned short * msg, unsigned short * mod, int wds, int exp, unsigned short * result);


Parameters:
  msg - Array of unsigned 16-bit integers holding the input.
  mod - Array of unsigned 16-bit integers holding the modulus. High bit must be set.
        Typically an RSA modulus always has the most-significant bit set. This
        implementation verifies and enforces that, because if the bit is not set, it
        might cause unexpected behaviors. The high bit of the modulus is the MSB
        of the first 16-bit integer of the array.
  wds - Number of 16-bit unsigned shorts in msg and mod.
  exp - Code for exponent: actual exponent is 2^exp+1. Acceptable values are 0, 1,
        16 that correspond to exponents of 2,3, and 65537, respectively.

Return Values:
  result Array of 16-bit integers holding the result on exit.
```

### RSA Key Pair

MODULUS:
BEDB6B21E12D2B6EB590EC129FCC847EA4C00BE41CA530A5FA2CCDDE3B7DB3A0F50E6D3E348CD9258D7076973DD01FDC5B7E00F1F714F4E55C650DF88AAA293ED9376D2B0905F589108FB5C2835EA025D036F369891E5F5F3BA4F5E96CF25D164C1B26215B8D9627CDB95C22F00EBF50DF821A984E01309C1677B5D013E2BEEF

PUBLIC EXP(E):
010001

PRIVATE EXP(D):
A6898BC7FA5691C97EC1405D57F6FBBE0E404D9FF4A6E7F64C807FFAE4EA60AD9867C847394F95C340D1DB894934AC3879D54F39D3A203B78791DE48FBA65369B077BD6541AA8200392CA0BF56EEE2AA8478598852BFB537498095C087910176E1E90F92F8564F3012D7DC52B8D7145C40143F51229FE4416CEF50657511E2F1

### TRACES

```
!!!!   This Works   !!!!
-------------------------
|*** RSAEncryptKey: rsa_calc :: ENTER
|MSG (256):
|0000 01 2A 9E 34 EA 19 63 07 F9 AD A8 9B 02 5B D6 6D - .*.4..c......[.m
|0010 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|0020 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|0030 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|0040 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|0050 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|0060 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|0070 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|0080 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|0090 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|00A0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|00B0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|00C0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|00D0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|00E0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|00F0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|rsa_calc: 0 :: 
|rsa_calc result (256):
|0000 2D 0A F1 93 29 6A 47 D7 94 A6 16 32 E8 AD 2D 3B - -...)jG....2..-;
|0010 72 64 7B 23 55 79 1B 71 A1 34 AD E4 E5 E7 E6 FA - rd{#Uy.q.4......
|0020 6D 78 AA 6E 7F 32 D0 BF 26 87 3A 5F 8F B9 23 42 - mx.n2..&.:_..#B
|0030 C7 02 D6 8B 70 24 76 90 59 40 A3 42 D5 B5 2B 00 - ....p$v.Y@.B..+.
|0040 CB 08 A4 C3 07 E7 12 4D 02 C0 2D 3A 43 15 27 41 - .......M..-:C.'A
|0050 17 42 F7 B0 F8 B7 06 B1 25 D9 90 12 88 C1 05 16 - .B..............
|0060 75 64 8E 87 AA 68 82 96 1E 3E 23 F7 32 10 E5 8A - ud...h...>#.2...
|0070 17 D4 39 18 21 FC 5A C3 38 BB 7F CB DA B0 D2 85 - ..9.!.Z.8......
|0080 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|0090 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|00A0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|00B0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|00C0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|00D0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|00E0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|00F0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|*** RSAEncryptKey: :: EXIT


!!!!   DOES NOT DECRYPT   !!!!
-------------------------------------
|*** RSAEncryptKey: rsa_calc :: ENTER
|MSG (256):
|0000 FA 68 E9 19 F5 D2 64 E0 F6 A8 FB 88 DC 67 35 C0 - .h....d......g5.
|0010 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|0020 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|0030 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|0040 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|0050 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|0060 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|0070 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|0080 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|0090 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|00A0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|00B0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|00C0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|00D0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|00E0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|00F0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|rsa_calc: 0 :: 
|rsa_calc result (256):
|0000 36 B8 4D F2 76 DA 21 31 A3 8E C8 26 75 84 52 48 - 6.M.v.!1...&u.RH
|0010 3B CE 87 15 58 D9 F0 21 04 CE A0 83 9E 5E 58 31 - ;...X..!.....^X1
|0020 19 CF 82 70 00 BD A2 6D 2C E8 34 F4 27 D1 B2 4C - ...p...m,.4.'..L
|0030 1A F4 19 1D DA C4 B6 CD 10 C2 29 32 B6 85 E7 CB - ..........)2....
|0040 BD 4D 53 70 B3 27 47 B8 87 48 0C FD 86 B8 C0 4C - .MSp.'G..H.....L
|0050 B4 B8 23 4C 11 8C A7 93 41 2E AF E4 FF F1 EC 9A - ..#L....A.......
|0060 44 13 FF DB 9B ED B6 9E E2 2A 11 41 64 C5 2C E0 - D........*.Ad.,.
|0070 FE 4D 05 30 EE 49 9A 7A C5 46 BD 17 2F 87 72 D1 - .M.0.I.z.F../.r.
|0080 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|0090 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|00A0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|00B0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|00C0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|00D0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|00E0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|00F0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - ................
|*** RSAEncryptKey: :: EXIT
```

Comment: Nevermind my previous comment, the e, d, and N do in fact seem to be consistent. I must've made some mistake.

Comment: The problem is that your plaintext in the second case is **larger** than your modulus. You are specifying only the high-order 16 bytes and leaving the remaining 112 bytes as zero. Thus those first 16 bytes must be less than or equal to 0xbedb6b21e12d2b6eb590ec129fcc84, the high 16 bytes of n.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you President James K. Polk.  Your comments resolved the issue.  I wouldn't mind understanding better, so please comment if you can.  It appears you are indicating that if I treat the first 16 bytes as a 16 byte integer, then the encryption block cannot be a larger integer than the Modulus, I don't really understand why.  I don't really see the relationship between what I want to encrypt versus the key used to encrypt it.

However, shifting the 16 bytes in the encryption block (I shifted it 16 bytes).  Every encryption/decryption appears to work (so far anyway).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure which part you're having trouble with. RSA works with integers, so the bytes you have displayed must somehow be interpreted by rsa_calc as an integer. rsa_calc evidently does it in a pretty standard manner, each byte is treated as two hex digits of the base 16 representation of the integer. But since the modulus is 1024 bits (128 bytes) rsa_calc is using the entire 128 bytes from 0000 to 007f inclusive to form the integer. If you really wanted to encrypt just 0xFA68E919F5D264E0F6A8FB88DC6735C0 then place those 16 bytes in memory at 0070 to 007f and leave the other bytes zero.